# Which type of index is needed for has_many relation with where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a frequently used query where `User` model `has_many :payments`:

```
current_user.payments.where(status: "succeeded").order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(params[:size])
```

Which of these indexes would I need? Or would I need all three of them?

```
add_index :payments, :user_id
add_index :payments, :status, order: {created_at: :desc})
add_index :payments, [:user_id, :status], order: {created_at: :desc})
```

**Edit:**

The `page()` and `per()` in the query are from [kaminari gem](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari). Do I need additional indexes for these?

Comment: A query can only use one index at a time and which one gets used depends on a number of factors.  `add_index :payments, [:user_id, :status]` seems to be a good place to start since the payment's user and status are what you are querying for.

Comment: On a side note you should just use `.order(created_at: :desc)` instead of a string. That will create a less ambigeous query.

Comment: @dbugger thanks for the info.  Does `add_index :payments, [:user_id, :status]` cover a query such as `current_user.payments.order(created_at: :desc)`? Or should I add the additional indexes in that case?

Comment: @dbugger Also, i noticed you did not suggest to include the `, order: {created_at: :desc})` part of the index. Is there a reason I shouldn't include it?

Comment: @loop - start with one index, see if your performance is good.  If not, tune.  Adding indexes adds time to every insert, update and delete operation, and as stated above -- a query can only ever use one index.  Adding indexes does not guarantee faster query performance.